# Creating an auto_ptr with 2 arguments

Tags: c++, compilation, auto-ptr

Hi I have a compile error when I run this code:

```
std::auto_ptr<MyDisplay> m_display =
    std::auto_ptr<MyDisplay>(new MyDisplay(this, m_displayController));
```

The error is this one:

```
error C2664: 'MyDisplay::MyDisplay(DemoWindow *,DisplayController*)':
   cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' to 'DisplayController*'
```

However when I pass only one argument the code is correct:

```
std::auto_ptr<DisplayController> m_displayController =
    std::auto_ptr<DisplayController>(US_NEW(DisplayController, this));
```

What is the proper way to create the pointer in the auto_ptr with 2 arguments?

Comment: What's `MyDisplay`? And as @sharth says, why are you using `auto_ptr` because unless you have a *very* good reason, don't!

Comment: Please don't use [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr), it's been __deprecated__. You're going to cause yourself no end of heartache. Please use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

Comment: This code is why `std::auto_ptr` is terrible: https://gist.github.com/sharth/637dfafbf579183f5d7b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, it appears that `m_displayController` is an `std::auto_ptr<DisplayController>`, while the `MyDisplay` constructor expects a `DisplayController*`.

Try :

```
std::auto_ptr<MyDisplay> m_display =
    std::auto_ptr<MyDisplay>(new MyDisplay(this, m_displayController.get()));
```

or better yet, make the constructor compatible with `std::auto_ptr<DisplayController>`.

As an aside : the choice of `std::auto_ptr` here is probably not the best. You might want to [read up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) on the different types of smart pointers, and the different behaviors they have.

Comment: And then he's passed a `std::auto_ptr` by value, which means that the original `mDisplayController` then points to null... Which is why `std::auto_ptr` is terrible...

Comment: How come I didn't see that I needed a DisplayController*, pretty obvious. Thanks it did the trick. I don't get why the displayController would be null after? I am passing a pointer right?

Comment: @sharth Unless, of course, that's what he wants.  (I've used `auto_ptr` in the interface of an inter-thread queue.  It more or less guarantees that only one thread at a time has access to the object.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to clarify your idea of creating the auto pointer, which I hope will help.
Your goal here is to create an auto_ptr holding a DisplayController*. You could write

```
m_displayController = std::auto_ptr<DisplayController>( new DisplayController(x, y) );
```

Or have a function that returns a pointer, like this :

```
m_displayController = std::auto_ptr<DisplayController>( US_NEW(x,y) );
```

You can check out a simple example [here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72827938dbf68dcc)